# Multiple tableviews for One Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hey Friends I'm having diffculty in implementing that,I have 10 tableViews in my project and all the tableviews have data already loaded what I want is to show a single cell Which will be shown When any of tableview have no data the cell I have made is in the Xib.How can i do this..Please Help
I'm doing like this in cellforrowatindexpath...

```
static NSString *noDataAlertCellIdentifier = @"myNoDataAlertCell";
        NoDataAlertTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:noDataAlertCellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"NoDataAlertTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:noDataAlertCellIdentifier];
                [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:noDataAlertCellIdentifier];
            }
        cell.lblNoDataAlert.text = @"No Data Found";
        return cell;
```

Comment: An interesting approach of cells registration, but you've missed assignment at the second `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: The assignment is still missing, you are not using the returned value of the last `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Comment: can u give me the example

Comment: @A-Live is correct that you're not capturing the value returned from the second `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call. However, this isn't a great way to handle it. You should call `registerWithNib` in your `viewDidLoad` and remove the `dequeue` code duplication.

Comment: At the first line you are assigning the result of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to the `cell` variable, you are doing it again if there is no data but don't do it after you determine that the cell must be registered and perform registration.

Comment: You also have two local variables called `cell`. I'd rename the second one to `noDataCell` or something similar.

Comment: Thnxx For the help guysss...